# Message Attributes and Payload in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using AMQP Java client i want to use message attributes properties like ,Message priority,Delivery mode, Message publishing timestamp,Expiration period, etc.how to set it on channel.basicPublish();

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked through the RabbitMQ tutorials (http://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) they have lots of good examples which are in both java and python which should give you a good basis to start using RabbitMQ